# Not able to upload the file in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("file"));
element.click();
element.sendKeys("C:\Users\Minesh\Desktop\arch_logo.png);
```

The Above test case is just to select the file.
we have another button to upload the file. 
If we run the program,only the window is getting pop up. 
File is not getting selected.
And the input type is of button.
Please guide for the query

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each backslash so it can be considered as a file path:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("file"))
      .sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Minesh\\Desktop\\arch_logo.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

@user6203568 - You can update your code as below:

It should work as it is working for me. And give your test method priority as per your requirement. Just for Example I gave priority here as @Test(priority = 1). I hope it should work for you.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void CERTIFICATIONSSCREENUploadCertficationFilesValidation()
            throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        //Click on File Upload Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='certificationFile']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Set the file name in the clipboard. Also following line of code will search file in your computer so make sure you provide correct file path.

        StringSelection s = new StringSelection("C:\\Doc\\CertificationFile.xls");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```